# Get DateTime from internet service and compare to LocalTime in a split second

Tags: c#, datetime, asynchronous, compare

I am trying to get DateTime from an internet service and then compare it to my localTimeDate from Computer. My problem is sometimes it has one second difference and thats logical because it takes some miliseconds to get one variable and the other.
Is there any way to get those two variables and compare it in miliseconds?
I thought something like asynchronous loading but I have no idea how to do it or if this can work.

Here is my code

```
     private string GetTime()
            {
                try
                {
                   MessageServiceType.Test : MessageServiceType.Production);
                    ITimeServiceContract timeServiceContract = new TimeServiceTestClient();
                    DateTime icisTime = timeServiceContract.GetTimeStamp();
                    DateTime icisDateTime = icisTime.ToLocalTime();
                    return icisDateTime.ToString();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    NLogger.NLogger.SilentLog(ex.ToString());
                }

                return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

     private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DateTime icisDateTime = DateTime.Parse(GetTime());
                lblIcisNetTime.Text = GetTime();
                lblLocalTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                CompareDateTimes(icisDateTime, DateTime.Now);
            }

     private void CompareDateTimes(DateTime icisNetTime, DateTime pcTime)
            {
                if (icisNetTime.Hour  > pcTime.Hour ||
                    icisNetTime.Hour  < pcTime.Hour ||
                    icisNetTime.Minute > pcTime.Minute + 1 ||
                    icisNetTime.Minute + 1 < pcTime.Minute ||
                    icisNetTime.Day > pcTime.Day + 1 ||
                    icisNetTime.Day < pcTime.Day ||
                    icisNetTime.Month > pcTime.Month + 1 ||
                    icisNetTime.Month < pcTime.Month ||
                    icisNetTime.Year > pcTime.Year + 1 ||
                    icisNetTime.Year < pcTime.Year)

                    XtraMessageBox.Show(this,
                                        "Your PC clock is wrong!",
                                        "Wrong Time and Date", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that there is latency in the request from the remote server (even if it's as small as say, 5ms), and that sometimes, because of that latency, the moment you capture the computer's current time, the second may be different from the server's.

Because of this, directly comparing the hours, minutes, etc is going to fail sometimes no matter what you do. It isn't a matter of the code not running fast enough.

Instead, try comparing the timestamp you get from the remote server to the local computer time, +/- 30ms or whatever you find the acceptable latency to be.

You may be interested in reading about how this is addressed in the Network Time Protocol as well:
[Network Time Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)

Comment: @BrianMurrah Thanks. I was hoping to also show the same time based on the two variables and not just compare it with +/- 30ms.